# Android : Build a video

Tags: android, video, bitmap

I'm trying to develop an app on Android and I would like to know if it's possible to build a video with photos.
I actually have several pictures (Bitmap), and I would like to create a video (programmatically) by animating these pictures I have. At the end, I would have a video file..

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible in android and can be achieved in two ways.

First and most common one, that most of the apps in android follow is to let users select certain images and then upload them to a server where you can use any video maker tool to create your desired slideshow and then send the video back to user's phone by provide a download link.

Second method is to create the video locally on the device which would require a native library like ffmpeg compiled for android which provides basic functionality of creating video but it doesn't provide any way to apply transition effects between images for that you can use another library ImageMagick. you need to have knowledge about NDK for this

follow this links for more details on [how to import native lib in android](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)

Comment: Good answer. Also to note: since video editing is very processor-intensive and mobile systems have comparatively limited resources to personal computers, you might want to go with the first options of actually doing the editing "off the device" but still "fake it" with the first part of this answer.

Comment: I cannot upvote... I'm too new! hah
Once I have my libffmpeg.so, what do I do? I can't find any good help for that.

Comment: Its ok you can upvote later..
To ans your question.. once you have a compiled version of libffmpeg.so you can run various commands to create video according to your required conditions
ffmpeg is a quite powerful tool that lets you do various things with video you create .. you can provide audio input , video codec and audio and video encoders for your video as well 
refer these links to learn what all you can do with ffmpeg

http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html
http://linuxers.org/tutorial/ffmpeg-tutorial-beginners

Comment: more links here 

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?19342-Frequently-requested-FFMPEG-command-examples-for-Wowza   http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

you can also put up another question how to run these commands in android and provide me link here or search it on stackoverflow